# how to make some part of the page as unauthenticated in django?

Tags: python, django, authentication

I have a Django project which uses JWT as the authentication class. But for certain pages of my app has no authentication. But still when I make request it returns the following thing.

```
{
    "detail": "You do not have permission to perform this action."
}
```

My authentication classes are here

```
REST_FRAMEWORK = {
    'DEFAULT_AUTHENTICATION_CLASSES': [
        'rest_framework_simplejwt.authentication.JWTAuthentication',
    ],
    'DEFAULT_PERMISSION_CLASSES': [
                'rest_framework.permissions.IsAuthenticated',
    ],
}
```

My views file is here

```
class Hello(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        return Response('Hello')
```

So how do I achieve this thing?

Comment: You can try by settting `permission_classes = [AllowAny]` instead of `authentication_classes`. By importing `AllowAny` from `rest_framework.permissions`.

Comment: That's true. Just now I figured it out! Anyways thanks!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable/bypass the authentication by setting `authentication_classes` as well as well as `permission_classes` as empty list like this:

```py
class Hello(APIView):
    authentication_classes = []
    permission_classes = []
    def post(self, request):
        return Response('Hello')
```

or if you want to use a function based approach you could use decorators to set their values like this:

```py
from rest_framework.decorators import authentication_classes, permission_classes

@api_view(['POST'])    
@authentication_classes([])
@permission_classes([])
def hello(request):
   return Response('Hello')
```

Comment: Since I use class based view. If you have a code for class based view then update it. I'll accept